# Transform a TextFieldValue return to Double (Kotlin, Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

there!

I'm writing a BMI calculator with Jetpack Compose.
I set two "TextFieldValue" functions to input the height and weight of the user. Both functions return "text" that I can't convert it to Double type so I can do the Maths!

It's beeing over 3 hours that I'm stucked on it!
I'm starting at Android Development, so your help will be very appreciated!
Well, thank you very much!

I have tried:

```
// Insert function:

fun insertWeight (): TextFieldValue {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
    }
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
        },
        label = {
            Text (text = "Weight")
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text (text = "Insert your weight in Kilograms")
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number)
    )
    return text
}
```

And then (In the MainActivity)

```
// I couldn't find out how to do it directly without passing by String (I even don't know if it is right"
val weight: Double = insertWeight().toString().toDouble()
```

I also have tried another stuff, as change the function type from "TextFieldValue" to "Double", and then change the return in the function to "return text.toString().toDouble()", and then I realized that is a very dummy thing to try hahahaha the compose function will fatally terminate the app if type mismatch!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `composable function` in normal function or cannot return data (because composable function is not a normal function , it's a widget or Ui) , you can achieve the above thing from below code. Hope it helps you.

```
@Composable
fun TextFieldValueScreen() {

    var weight by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var height by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var total by remember { mutableStateOf(0.0) }
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        CommonTextField(
            title = "Weight",
            placeholder = "Insert your weight in Kilograms",
            text = weight,
            onValueChange = { weight = it }
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        CommonTextField(
            title = "Height",
            placeholder = "Insert your height in meter",
            text = height,
            onValueChange = { height = it }
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Button(onClick = {
            if (height.isNotEmpty() && weight.isNotEmpty()) {
                total = (weight.toDouble()) / (height.toDouble() * height.toDouble())
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Please type height and weight", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }) {
            Text(text = "Calculate")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        if (total != 0.0)
            Text(
                text = "BMI is ${String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", total)}",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 25.sp,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic,
                )
            )
    }

}

@Composable
fun CommonTextField(
    title: String,
    placeholder: String,
    text: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {

    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        label = {
            Text(text = title)
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text(text = placeholder)
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Phone)
    )

}
```

***Output***

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!
I didn't know that composable functions are not supposed to return data.
I don't know if it is a dummy question, and sorry for that in advance, but can you always change the data type inside the composable function? As you did in the Button?